# como quitar símbolos y letras al enviar datos de un ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

estoy enviando los datos de **price** tiene 
este valor `var price = $("#totalprice").text();`

```
Ejemplo : price="$6000 precio";
```

los mando en un **ajax** a un metodo **post** quiero que me envié llegue como

```
Quiero que pase a esto : price=6000;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con esta expresión regular

```js
var price="$6000 precio";
price = price.replace(/\D/g,'');
console.log(price);
```

Saludos!